# In Wordpress is there a way to globally secure ALL cookies?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, cookies, server

I am attempting to secure all cookies on my wordpress install including (and especially) cookies that come from plugins. I am hosting on Wpengine, using nginx as the primary server in combinantion with apache 2.4.

I have currently attempted setting the httpOnly and secure flags in the .htaccessfile and in our nginx instance.

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HttpOnly"
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure"
```

I also have the following lines included in my wp_config file

```
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
```

This did not secure my third party cookies. Is there any other ways to globally secure all cookies?

Comment: cookies can setup from js or php code. if some 3rd party plugin set  its cookie through js, then you should to change the whole code of the plugin, which related to cookies ( if they setup cookies through js, than they expecting to read it through js ). So, your question is too broad to get one answer for all wp core, 3rd part plugins, themes. you can provide which one not working( not changing to httpOnly )

Comment: Primarily I'm looking at 3rd party plugin cookies.